# Nginx Ingress Route traffic based on X-Forwarded-Prefix

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am looking for a way to ingress controller to reroute the traffic based on the `hostname` and `x-forwarded-prefix` header.

`api.gateway.contour.com` --> with header `x-forwaded-prefix=/api/account-service` --> Should route to `account-service` in Kuberenetes

and similarly

`api.gateway.contour.com` --> with header `x-forwaded-prefix=/api/billing-service` --> Should route to `billing-service` in Kuberenetes

Comment: Did you considered filter by the URL instead?

Comment: @mWatney, could you please help with a snippet of the usecase using the filter by URL? I am wondering how do I achieve with it, ingress obecjt

Comment: Please, check if something like this would solve your problem: https://theithollow.com/2019/02/13/kubernetes-ingress/